# How does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{\pi}{4})^{2k} $ = $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{\pi^{2}}{16})^{k} - 1 $

Tags: sequences-and-series

How is it that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\frac{\pi}{4})^{2k}  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{\pi^{2}}{16})^{k} - 1 $$

Where is that $- 1$ coming from?

Comment: Do you see how the starting index is different on each side? Perhaps it's easier if you write out the first three or so terms on each side.

Comment: come from extra term k =0 in the right side summation.

Comment: Yes, I do.  I also see how the numerator and denominator are being squared.

Comment: Does it have to do with the exponent?

Comment: I notice the difference, I'm trying to get the idea behind it.  I think it has to do with the exponent, because similar problems do not have any such minuses unless they have the exponent.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with the exponent. Write out the first $4$ terms on the left and the first $5$ on the right. What do you get?

Comment: They're staggered, with the one on the right starting with a $\frac{\pi^{2}}{16}^0 $ turning into a one that has to be removed.  Does k have to be 0 to solve this?

Comment: BTW - T. Bongers - I'd be happy to rep you if you submit the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $-1$ has nothing to do with the exponent and is not part of the summation. The right side could be re-written as

$$\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}{16}\right)^0-1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}{16}\right)^k$$

The first $2$ terms will cancel out.

Comment: So to solve the sum, the exponent needs to be cleared of the coefficient 2? Thus: $\frac{1}{1-\frac{\pi^{2}}{16}} -1$

Comment: @DonShrinkle Not sure what you mean about the exponent needing to be cleared of the coefficient 2.  I'm assuming the right side of the equation is a form you're more comfortable with.  Either side of the equality involves a geometic series with a common ratio of $\left(\dfrac\pi4\right)^2$, or $\dfrac{\pi^2}{16}$.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant that the 2 needed to be cleared off the exponent 2k in the left side of the equation.

Comment: @DonShrinkle Just as long as you realize what the common ratio is.  It could also be calculated as $\dfrac1{1-(\frac\pi4)^2}-1$ or $\dfrac{\frac{\pi^2}{16}}{1-\frac{\pi^2}{16}}$.